# Converting Python 3 String of Bytes of Unicode - `str(utf8_encoded_str)` back to unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode

Well, let me introduce the problem first.

I've got some data via POST/GET requests. The data were UTF-8 encoded string. Little did I know that, and converted it just by `str()` method. And now I have full database of "nonsense data" and couldn't find a way back.

## Example code:

**unicode_str** - this is the string I should obtain

**encoded_str** - this is the string I got with POST/GET requests - **initial data**

**bad_str** - the data I have in the Database at the moment and I need to get unicode from.

So apparently I know how to convert:
**unicode_str** =(`encode`)=> **encoded_str** =(`str`)=> **bad_str**

But I couldn't come up with solution back:
**bad_str** =(`???`)=> **encoded_str** =(`decode`)=> **unicode_str**

```
In [1]: unicode_str = 'Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy'

In [2]: unicode_str
Out[2]: 'Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy'

In [3]: encoded_str = unicode_str.encode("UTF-8")

In [4]: encoded_str
Out[4]: b'P\xc5\x99\xc3\xadli\xc5\xa1 \xc5\xbelu\xc5\xa5ou\xc4\x8dk\xc3\xbd k\xc5\xaf\xc5\x88 \xc3\xbap\xc4\x9bl \xc4\x8f\xc3\xa1belsk\xc3\xa9 \xc3\xb3dy'

In [5]: bad_str = str(encoded_str)

In [6]: bad_str
Out[6]: "b'P\\xc5\\x99\\xc3\\xadli\\xc5\\xa1 \\xc5\\xbelu\\xc5\\xa5ou\\xc4\\x8dk\\xc3\\xbd k\\xc5\\xaf\\xc5\\x88 \\xc3\\xbap\\xc4\\x9bl \\xc4\\x8f\\xc3\\xa1belsk\\xc3\\xa9 \\xc3\\xb3dy'"

In [7]: new_encoded_str = some_magical_function_here(bad_str) ???
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You turned a bytes object to a string, which is just a representation of the bytes object. You can obtain the original bytes object by using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (credits to Mark Tolonen for the suggestion), then a simple `decode()` will do the job.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(bad_str).decode('utf-8')
'Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy'
```

Since you were the one who generated the strings, using `eval()` would be safe, but why not be safer?

Comment: well, I had `eval` also in mind, but since I don't know what data is there and there is a lot of data, I was hoping I could evade this - thus not mentioning it. But thanks :)

Comment: @darkless It doesn't matter what the strings you saved look like. As long as you followed the procedure of get utf-8 string -> encode it to a bytes object -> turn **this** to a string and store to your database, you guarantee those strings to be harmless bytes objects.

Comment: True, I didn't realized that every stored string is "b'...' " which eval should interpret as b'...' :) Thanks for the remark!

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` does the same thing without the security risk of `eval`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen This is excellent. I have updated the answer accordingly. Also, this function sounds a bit familiar and I wouldn't be surprised if I hadn't "learnt" about it before but forgot, since I have never needed it. Need better memory for next time!

Comment: @darkless I just want to draw your attention to the fact that there is a safer version of `eval()` which also fits your requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Please do not use eval, instead:

```
import codecs
s = 'žluťoučký'
x = str(s.encode('utf-8'))

# strip quotes
x = x[2:-1]

# unescape
x = codecs.escape_decode(x)[0].decode('utf-8')

# profit
x == s
```

Comment: Thanks for non-eval version, I was missing `escape_decode` to turn double-slashes to single-slashes. I can't find docs to the method though: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html

Comment: Wow this is very nice to use.